# Implicity Function Theorem - Existence and DIfferentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

The proof I'm referring to is this [arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.2066.pdf)

> By the continuity of F , there exists an
>   open non-degenerate n-dimensional parallelepiped X, centered at $a$ and
>   contained in X ′ , whose edges are parallel to the coordinate axes such that
>   for every x in X we have $F (x, b_1 ) < 0$ and $F (x, b_2 ) > 0$

I can see how if $x < a$ and $x>a$ it $F$ would be $<0$ and $>0$ but I can't see why the $b$ variable would determine if the function is greater or less than zero, independently of our $x$ point. The "center at $a$" part is tripping me up. I can't visualize why this must be true.

The second question I have is of this section:

> let $t \ne 0$ be small enough so that $x + te_j$ belongs to X. Putting $P = (x, f (x))$
>   and $Q = (x+te_j , f (x+te j )) $, we notice that F vanishes at P and Q.

Why do we notice Q vanishes? Is it because we've chosen $t$ to be small enough that we can say that $f(x)$ is linear?

Comment: You should give enough context so that the reader does not need to follow a link and read a paper to figure out what the question is about.

Comment: I was hoping people would be somewhat familiar with this proof, but I guess not. I tried to avoid having a post that was 60% quotations.